# how to run az storage blob download-batch command in script .ps1?

Tags: azure, powershell

I would like to make a script in powershell (.ps1) where you run the following command:

```
az storage blob download-batch -d. --pattern * .py -s MyContainer --account-name MyStorageAccount
```

But failing, could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Have you tried to use ```az storage blob delete-batch -s MyContainer --account-name MyStorageAccount --pattern '*.py'```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you error message is not clear , i am gonna explain few points which could cause the issue with the command, but please make sure to include https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example next time.

Here is some prerequisite which you need to keep in mind before running this command:

- Please ensure you have installed the right version of Azure CLI.

  **Current version of Azure CLI is 2.0.76**

  You can get the more details here:
- Please ensure if you have the right permission if you are using login mode to download the files.
- Please ensure you have right set of SAS token if you are using SAS to access the blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

I have ran the command and it worked for me using login mode, here is the detail for the same:

[image]

Feel free to tag me in your conversation if you need further assistance, hope it helps.

Comment: hello, thanks for replying.
I want to create a script in .ps1 where I can pass some data through parameters. I was able to run straight on powershell but wanted it to run from a .ps1 file.

Comment: You can check this blog for passing param to your .ps1 file , https://windows.tips.net/T002902_Passing_Parameters_to_a_PowerShell_Script.html

Comment: @marcelosilva Please accept as an answer if it helped as it will help other who have the same ask.